# How to give Typography-like style to an input element with Material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like my Typography field to become editable, so I transform it into an input.
Now I would like this input to have the same style.
How to do it?
I tried copying the produced css to the input, but it is tedious and seemed not perfect.

Here is a code sandbox to illustrate: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-stonebraker-le1eq?file=/index.js

Comment: Can you take a look at "naked input" at here: https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#customized-inputs to see if it works.

Comment: Thanks ShinaBR2, InputBase helps a little in that it resets default input styles. But it does not solve the first part of my question: how to extract the style of Typography? The perfect thing would be ```<InputBase inputComponent={<Typography variant="h4" />} />``` but this does not work.

Comment: I think you can use `classes` props for `InputBase` component, reference [here](https://material-ui.com/api/input-base/). Then you need to hard code or copy css from Typography, not sure why you need so. But why not use different component instead? One for typography, one for input.

Comment: Yes, I can copy the css to InputBase or input using classes or className, it is tedious but works fine. My question is: is there a better way to grab the style from Typography?

Comment: No, when working with material-ui, in most cases, you just need high level, touching on pure css is a good point that show you're doing the wrong thing.

Comment: I understand. Then how could I style my input to look like a Typography?

Comment: Have you look at my first link, at "nake input" example, it looks like a typography. If you need to have font-family, maybe you need to custom style by using `makeStyles` or so. Example using `makeStyle` [here](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#hook-api).

Comment: Alright, thank you @ShinaBR for your help, InputBase indeed is a little improvement to input. As for applying the style of Typography, for now I will keep copying css. If I find a better solution I will post it here.

Comment: Happy coding :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workaround for you, but keep in mind that this is not ideal because if you change the current Typography component you have to find its classes again in the chrome devtools, and also the typography with the `diaplay: none` is necessary for material to render the styles...

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Button, InputBase, TextField, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";

function App() {
 const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = React.useState(false);
 const [value, setValue] = React.useState("Edit me");

 const toggleIsEditing = () => setIsEditing((b) => !b);

 if (isEditing) {
   return (
     <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
       <input
         className="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-h4 MuiTypography-displayInline"
         value={value}
         onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
       />
       <Typography style={{ display: "none" }} />
        <Button size="small" onClick={toggleIsEditing}>
          Done
        </Button>
       </div>
    );
  }

  return (
   <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Typography variant="h4" display="inline">
        {value}
      </Typography>
      <Button size="small" onClick={toggleIsEditing}>
        Edit
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

Comment: Thank you Adir, I like this approach! It provides accurate styling, is less tedious than copying individual css lines, and it seems more future proof in the sense that I can update material-ui package and hope that the class names stay the same. Do you use this technique personally?

Comment: In order to match the classNames dynamically, you could potentially use a `const ref = React.useRef()` on the `<Typography  ref={ref} />` component and then set `className` on the input to `<input className={ref.current?.className} />`. The one caveat is that you must wait till the second render to show the editable component. The ref won't have a value until after the first render.

Comment: @denski nice approach!

Answer (score 4):

```
<Typography suppressContentEditableWarning={true} contentEditable={true} className={text} onChange={handleChange}>
    Some text
</Typography>
```

Css (to prevent the nasty looking border, when you click into the Typography):

```
text: {
  outline: `0 solid transparent`,
 }
```

Comment: The onChange doesn't seem to work. It doesn't have any event when changing.

Comment: In completion to this answer and my previous comment, you can use **onInput** because **onChange** doesn't seem to work. `<Typography suppressContentEditableWarning={true} contentEditable={true} onInput={(e) => console.log(e.target.innerText)} >Text</Typography>` But even then there are problems with the input cursor going back to the start if you use the state as the actual text. One solution would be to do it *onBlur*.

Answer (score 3):

**Material UI V5**

I made a reusable component to do that without using any manual class declaration or any content editable elements. Only used the material UI public APIs.

```
import InputBase, { InputBaseProps } from "@mui/material/InputBase";
import Typography, { TypographyProps } from "@mui/material/Typography";
import { useState } from "react";
import * as React from "react";

export interface EditableTypographyProps {
  /**
   * Handler calling when the text changed
   */
  onChange?: (value: string) => void;
}

const InputBaseWithChildren = ({
  children,
  ...props
}: InputBaseProps & { children?: React.ReactNode }) => {
  let value = "";
  if (children) {
    if (typeof children == "string" || typeof children == "number") {
      value = children.toString();
    }
  }

  return (
    <InputBase
      {...props}
      className={""}
      value={value}
      inputProps={{ className: props.className }}
    />
  );
};

/**
 * Displaying like a `Typography`. But acting as an `input`
 */
const EditableTypography = ({
  onChange: propsOnChange,
  ...props
}: EditableTypographyProps & TypographyProps) => {
  const [internalValue, setInternalValue] = useState("");

  const value = props.children || internalValue;

  const onChange = (value: string) => {
    if (propsOnChange) {
      propsOnChange(value);
    }
    setInternalValue(value);
  };

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    onChange(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Typography
      {...props}
      children={value}
      component={InputBaseWithChildren}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
};

export default EditableTypography;
```

Comment: I cannot try it now but it looks promising, thank you for sharing!